# Material Design Lite dynamically change color

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm using Material Design Lite ([getmdl.io](http://getmdl.io)) for my web app. I have a textbox with a floating `label`;

I want to change the underline color of the text field to a custom color, not one I defined as my primary color (the line that appears when you focus the textbox).

How can I change this color via either CSS or Javascript?

**Edit:**

This is how the MDL text fields are implemented but some JS is used to do the dynamic underline on the bottom.

You can also see an example in motion [here](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section)

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can show how MDL implement a text field ?

Comment: @XZKS I edited with examples

Comment: Check the webtool in chrome and set :focus o nthat and add !important to that to make sure :)

Comment: @Medda86 I'm not even sure what property to set or how to set it, unfortunately

Comment: @tommy.bonderenka not sure if you already checked, but I updated my answer, just FYI, it is a bit complete :)

Comment: @dippas thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using [MDL](https://getmdl.io/) and not the regular Materialize.CSS, and by doing a few tests, that line comes from this script:

```
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
```

MDL provides 19 possible colors to have, which you can have by adding `--color` to class where the element you want to change.

But that's for `background-color` in the element, in this case it is applied to pseudo element `::after`, so you can use a custom color as you wish using color `teal`

```css
div .mdl-textfield__label:after {
  background: teal
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a an already existent [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mdlhut/pen/vOvydM) with all possible colors

You can always build your own theme [here](https://getmdl.io/customize/index.html)

Comment: This is working to a degree - but now I'm getting my custom color and my primary color both underlining the text input field

Comment: care to share a link to help you out?

Comment: I don't really have a way to do that unfortunately. I did notice that you're using Materialize instead of MDL though, so I'm assuming that has something to do with it.

Comment: Yeah I just looked at the docs - definitely slightly different but close!

Comment: @tommy.bonderenka Ok let me see then the MDL docs..I'll get back to you ASAP

Comment: I'm currently looking [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/textfield/_textfield.scss) at the textfield css file but I don't see anything involving outline or border that has to do with is-focused or :focus

Comment: oops! was a mistake! hah

Answer (score 3):

```css
.mdl-textfield__label:after{
    background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
}
```

Not sure if `!important` is necessary, but it comes in handy when modifying a CSS framework.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to change the text color? This worked wonders but I need help here. https://jsfiddle.net/90u6Lxc4/5/ to make it white after click and not white the whole time like @RonRoyston would do for me.

Comment: @BillyFerguson do you mean the label text or the input text?

Comment: The floating label text that is currently dark blue ish when you click into the input.

Comment: @BillyFerguson `.mdl-textfield.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label { color: #FAFAFA; } ` https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/vey6081L/

Comment: we need to not overwrite the original style though.https://jsfiddle.net/vey6081L/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of the floating text.  No need to hack at the background-color.  Here's your available colors (and MDL codes) - https://rack.pub/swatch.

`mdl-color-text--yellow-500`

https://codepen.io/rhroyston/pen/YWVBkJ